# Why did my Flow (for SharePoint list) run for all items in my list?

Tags: power-automate

The flow I created has been in production for a few weeks without issue. Expected behavior for the flow - when a new item is added to the SharePoint list, a meeting invite is emailed out for that list item.  I added a new item today, and then my flow ran for all of the other items in the list (~50).  I can't figure out why.

Do I need a [Get Item] action added after the [When an item is created] trigger so that the flow is only grabbing the item that was just created (and not any other items)?

[image: My flow]

I expected the Flow to only run for the newly created item, and for no other items.

Comment: I had a similar experience. I believe it must just be a bug in the implementation of the control by Microsoft. I am thinking about defensively checking the creation date and then only doing the action if it is today's date.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you do not have to add `Get Item` action after the `When an item is created` trigger because the newly created item will be returned only.

I've created exactly the same flow on my own but it works just fine - two simple steps, hard to make any mistakes.

What about run history?

---

One the other hand, a few days ago I had very similar issue - some action in my flow apparently returned totally out-of-sense value. I did some investigation and it turned out that a long time ago this action might be configured in that way but not at present. Just one-off situation.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  Run history shows the Flow triggered once for each of the existing list items (about 80).  Looking into some of the run details, it looks like the Flow triggered as if each existing list item was created for the first time.

Comment: Are you sure that `When an item is created` action is not renamed `When an item is created or modified`?